# new ListItem for WFA

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, .net-4.5

I have this code below that works perfectly for ASP.NET.

However, when I try using it in WinForms .NET 4.5 , it gives me

*Error  1   The type or namespace name 'ListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

```
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeID,EmployeeFirstName,EmployeeLastName FROM Employees", cnn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2), dr.GetInt32(0).ToString()));
        }
    }

    cnn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

A `ListItem` does not exist in Windows Forms.

Simply add items to a `ListBox` like below:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeID,EmployeeFirstName,EmployeeLastName FROM Employees", cnn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2) +
                                         dr.GetInt32(0).ToString());
        }
    }
```

[ListBox.Items.Add() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add.aspx)

Comment: please delete your answer **because it has no value**. (btw, thank you for showing how to add items to listbox in kindergarten level)

Comment: @Johnjoe As he states in the answer `ListBoxItems` **Do Not** exist in winforms, the listBox takes an Object, you can create a custom class to add to the ListBox or just use the Items.Add Method as he as shown you, being insulting to someone who is trying to help you is being counter productive and rude. If I were you I would delete your comment and take a closer look at the correct answer and the link he shared with you.

Comment: The Asp.Net ListItem constructor that he is using has both a text and value component, the value would not be shown, the only way to duplicate it would to be use a custom class like I mentioned in my rebuttal.

Comment: @MarkHall - thanks for your comment. I could have expanded this answer to include a value for the control items but after his jerky response I didn't want to waste my time.